# How to exclude code from the Clover coverage report?

Tags: java, unit-testing, hudson, code-coverage, clover

Is there any way to hide classes or methods from being included in the Clover code coverage report?  We have some proof of concept code along side production quality code in the same directories.  This concept code is being included in the code coverage reports which is skewing our numbers.  We were wondering if we could annotate or mark them in such a way that Clover will ignore them when generating the report.

-- Update --

What about using a methodContext against a custom annotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I you are using [Clover as a Maven plugin](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CLOVER/Clover-for-Maven+2+and+3+User%27s+Guide), you can configure excluded classes.

```
<configuration>
  <excludes>
    <exclude>**/*Dull.java</exclude>
  </excludes>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks YMomb.  I am leaning towards that for classes but was hoping for a more universal solution that would also exclude methods.